# Accessing container mounted volumes in Kubernetes from docker container

Tags: file, docker, kubernetes, environment-variables, volume

I am currently trying to access a file mounted in my Kubernetes container from a docker image. I need to pass the file in with a flag when my docker image is run.

The docker image is usually run (outside a container) using the command:

`docker run -p 6688:6688 -v ~/.chainlink-ropsten:/chainlink -it --env-file=.env smartcontract/chainlink local n -p /chainlink/.password -a /chainlink/.api`

Now I have sucessfully used the following config to mount my env, password and api files at /chainlink, but when attempting to access the files during the docker run I get the error:

`flag provided but not defined: -password /chainlink/.password`

The following is my current Kubernetes Deployment file

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: chainlink-deployment
  labels:
    app: chainlink-node
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: chainlink-node
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: chainlink-node
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: chainlink
          image: smartcontract/chainlink:latest
          args: [ "local", "n", "--password /chainlink/.password", "--api /chainlink/.api"]
          ports:
          - containerPort: 6689
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config-volume
              mountPath: /chainlink/.env
              subPath: .env
            - name: api-volume
              mountPath: /chainlink/.api
              subPath: .api
            - name: password-volume
              mountPath: /chainlink/.password
              subPath: .password
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: node-env
        - name: api-volume
          configMap:
            name: api-env
        - name: password-volume
          configMap:
            name: password-env
```

Is there some definition I am missing in my file that allows me to access the mounted volumes when running my docker image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `args` to:

```
args: [ "local", "n", "--password", "/chainlink/.password", "--api", "/chainlink/.api"]
```

The way you currently have it, it's thinking the whole string `--password /chainlink/.password`, include the space, is a single flag.  That's what the error:

```
flag provided but not defined: -password /chainlink/.password
```

is telling you.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't realize I was missing something so obvious.